# What does a zero state combined state vector for 2 qubits mean?

Tags: quantum-algorithms, quantum-gate, deutsch-jozsa-algorithm

I was fiddling with the quantum circuit used for Deutsch's algorithm and I was led to a zero state as a result which is bizarre. I don't know how to explain this result. [image]

***I'm using Nielsen and Chuang to study QC

Comment: You don't explain why you think the terms cancel out. Without that, it's hard for us to help...

Answer (score 1):

The terms of expression *do not cancel out* in the balanced function case.

We start with

$$\frac{1}{2} (|0\rangle|0 \oplus f(0)\rangle - |0\rangle|1 \oplus f(0)\rangle + |1\rangle|0 \oplus f(1)\rangle - |1\rangle|1 \oplus f(1)\rangle)$$

If $f(0) \neq f(1)$, consider the first two terms (the only ones which can cancel with each other, since the state of the first qubit is $|0\rangle$): the state of the second qubit in them is $|0 \oplus f(0)\rangle$ and $|1 \oplus f(0)\rangle$, which are different states no matter what the value of $f(0)$ is.

It will be helpful for you to consider the cases for $f(x) = x$ and $f(x) = 1-x$ separately to convince yourself that the cancellation doesn't happen.